# I get [Object Error] When I use a timer in IE Mobile

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, timer

I am trying to display 1 image after another in IE Mobile.  The following code works in IE Desktop but I get an [Object error] If I run it in IE Mobile.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
       var interval = 30;
       var _timer;
       var _index = 0;
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a href="#" title="Play Motion Clip from Beginning" onclick="test();">
            <img alt="Play Motion" src="../Images/play_green_controls.png" style="border-style: none; width: 32px; height: 32px; background-color: #000000; cursor: pointer;" id="btnPlay" />
        </a>
        <img alt="" src="../0000.jpg" id="imgLive" />
        <div id="divImage" style="width: 352px; height: 288px; display: none; background-image: url('Portal/Catalogues/000EC902F17F/3/2013/10/6/10/60b01a71-27f9-4122-ae8e-674e65a8b4dd/20131006102041027x75x0.04x0.40x.img00001.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        </div>
        <div id="divImageCache1" style="width: 352px; height: 288px; display: none;">
            <img alt="" src="../0000.jpg" id="imgCached" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            try {
                _timer = setInterval(swapImages(), interval);
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
        var imgCached = document.getElementById('imgCached');
        var imgLive = document.getElementById('imgLive');

        function OnImgLoaded() {
            imgLive.src = imgCached.src;
        }

        function swapImages() {
            imgCached.onload = OnImgLoaded();
            imgCached.src = 'my irl/' + '0000' + _index + '.jpg';
            _index = _index + 1;
            if (_index == 10) {
                _index = 0;
                clearTimeout(_timer);
            }
        }
       </script>
       </body>
</html>
```

To debug I changed the javascript to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            try {
                alert('hi1');
                _timer = setInterval(swapImages(), interval);
                alert('hi2');
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
        var imgCached = document.getElementById('imgCached');
        var imgLive = document.getElementById('imgLive');

        function OnImgLoaded() {
            imgLive.src = imgCached.src;
        }

        function swapImages() {
            alert('hi3');
            imgCached.onload = OnImgLoaded();
            imgCached.src = 'http://www.url.co.uk/Cloud/test/' + '0000' + _index + '.jpg';
            _index = _index + 1;
            if (_index == 10) {
                _index = 0;
                clearTimeout(_timer);
            }
            alert('hi4');
        }
       </script>
```

What happened was that I got 'hi1', 'hi3', 'hi4' then object error. the image DID change once.

Comment: `imgCached.onload = OnImgLoaded();` is wrong- replace it to: `imgCached.onload = OnImgLoaded;`.

Comment: and also replace `clearTimeout(_timer);` with `clearInterval(_timer);`

Comment: and for better debugging, in the `catch` block do `alert(e.description)`

Comment: @GalV thank you very much for that. I have done as you suggested. I get 'Object Expected' error now after 'hi4'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assining a function to setInterval, you are calling the function and assigning what every it returns.

Your code

```
_timer = setInterval(swapImages(), interval);
```

is actually doing this

```
_timer = setInterval(undefined, interval);
```

Your code needs to drop the `()` so you are not calling the function.

```
_timer = setInterval(swapImages, interval);
```

You also did it here:

```
imgCached.onload = OnImgLoaded();
```

---

Personally I would not use an interval, your images are NOT going to load in 30 ms. You a timeout after the images are loaded. Something like this would work.

```
var isRunning,
    timer,
    intervalMS = 30,
    imgLive = document.getElementById('imgLive');

function test() {
    _index = 0;
    isRunning = true;
    if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
    swapImages();
}

function setImageSrc (src) {
    imgLive.src = src;
    if(isRunning) timer = window.setTimeout(swapImages, intervalMS);        
}

function swapImages() {
    var imgCached = new Image();
    imgCached.onload = function() { 
        setImageSrc(this.src);
    };
    imgCached.onerror = function() { 
        setImageSrc("Error.jpg");
    }; 
    imgCached.src = 'http://www.informedmotion.co.uk/Cloud/test/' + '0000' + _index + '.jpg';
    _index = _index + 1;
    if (_index == 10) {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you were quite right. I have changed that to what you said. It now runs OK in IE desktop but in IE Mobile I get, 'hi1', Object Expected' error. Thanks for that though

Comment: You did the same exact thing in another place! `imgCached.onload = OnImgLoaded();` Edited original answer. If that does not solve it, is there a line number?

Comment: I should have added I get no alert boxes now.  Just straight away an Object Expected error...

Comment: I added window.setInterval instead of just setInterval and I got 'Object doesn't support this property or method' - if that helps?

Comment: I edited it with a way to ensure images are loaded before moving onto the next image in the series. Yours would just blow right past images that are not loaded.

Comment: Superb! Works really well. cant thank you enough! This is what I miss when working by myself the chance to learn off other people's experience.  thanks again!

Comment: one thing I have just noticed and this does not diffract from your excellent answer but I have declared an array var _imgs = [] and I assign to it 40 URLs.  The 1st 20 are displayed but the next 20 are not. It works on a deskstop browser and displays all 40 images. Is it because the cache on the browser filled up quickly because it is a mobile browser do you think?  Should I look to turn caching off? Will that affect the performance of rendering these images? Or should I declare a smaller array and replenish it with newer urls?

Comment: Are the images huge? I am not an IE Mobile Dev so I have no experience with that device. I doubt doing anything with the URL will make a difference. See if `imgCached.onload = function() { setImageSrc(this.src); imgCached = null};` helps out any. [i doubt it will]

Comment: Hi, i shall give that a go. Not holding out much hope like you said urself. Still I have a desktop version of my app and ur code certainly improves upon my one.. take care :)